# how to use renjin inside java application for creating multiple correlations

Tags: java, r, math, regression, renjin

I want to use java to perform multiple correlation using large datasets. I can't find any library which provides this. The closest I could find is located at [[https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/SpearmansCorrelation.html][1]](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/SpearmansCorrelation.html%5d%5b1%5d) but this only does partial correlation an not multiple. I suppose I could use R to do this but my datasets are very large (trillions) and I would like to benefit from using Java's performance (threading, multicore, etc). Is there a library which does multiple correlation that anyone is aware of? It would be also be great if the library could perform stepwise multiple regression.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably Apache Mahout - which provides a set of scalable algorithms on top of Hadoop.

https://mahout.apache.org/